# Unable to connect to Phoenix using JDBC

Tags: java, hadoop, jdbc, jar, apache-phoenix

I have a Hadoop Cluster set up with HBase and Phoenix and I'm trying to connect to Phoenix using JDBC, but I am sort of unable to get a successful connection.

I want to use JDBC to connect using Python 3.x but as for simple test purposes I set up a connection using Java in Eclipse.

I was originally using a 3rd party library (phoenixdb) for Python, but I started getting timeouts using this library (as my database grows). After this I changed some variables in the settings of my **hbase-site.xml**, to avoid timeout, but for some reason that didn't solve my problems using this 3rd party library.

So I tried to move on to JDBC and a Java project instead - at least for the testing.

I have the following Java code:

```
public class PhoenixTest {

    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver";
    static final String DB_URL1 = "jdbc:phoenix:https://xx.xx.xx.xx:8765/";
    static final String DB_URL2 = "jdbc:phoenix:xx.xx.xx.xx:8765/";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement st = null;

        try {
            Class.forName("org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver");

            System.out.println("Connecting to database..");

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL);
            st = conn.createStatement();

            st.close();
            conn.close();

        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (st != null)
                    st.close();
            } catch (SQLException se2) {
            }
            try {
                if (conn != null)
                    conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Finished!");
}
```

And with this piece of code and the client.jar it seems that the settings I changed are being recognized as the queries are taking 10 minutes (600.000 ms - which is what I changed it to from the default 60.000 ms) before the connection is closed unlike with the use of the phoenixdb library in which the connection is closed after using the default timeout (60.000 ms).

When I use `DB_URL2` I get the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed after attempts=36, exceptions:
Thu Apr 06 11:13:35 CEST 2017, null, java.net.SocketTimeoutException: callTimeout=60000, callDuration=80236: row 'SYSTEM:CATALOG,,' on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=hadoopslave,16020,1490706604328, seqNum=0
```

Which doesn't match my timeout time of 600.000 ms. However when using `DB_URL1` it seems to use the `client.jar` and the timeout time that I have set inside of the `.jar` (hbase-default.xml), which I have set to 300.000 ms, just to test which one is used. Using `DB_URL1` I get the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Can't get the locations
```

Which I assume means that it can't find the IP.

However I never completely get a successful connection so I was hoping someone would have some suggestions to what is going wrong?

Comment: try using the thin-client driver, also your jdbc url looks wrong - try this with thin - jdbc:phoenix:thin:url=http://localhost:8765 (thin driver class - org.apache.phoenix.queryserver.client.Driver )

Comment: I might have forgot to mention that I am not connecting it a localhost Phoenix service, but a remote one. This is the reason why I didn't write the IP in the question, but used `xx.xx.xx.xx` instead. Using your method I get `java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: <ip>:8765`

Comment: @PaulBastide But if I add __http__ to the url I get `java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.phoenix.shaded.com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('o' (code 111)): Expected space separating root-level values`. This means the URL I used is `jdbc:phoenix:thin:url=http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8765/` and the driver is `org.apache.phoenix.queryserver.client.Driver`

Comment: try just doing a curl -X POST to the server on that port and see what you get

Comment: @PaulBastide I am unsure of how to do this. Never used curl, but it should be easy to set up since my cluster is running on Ubuntu. I will let you know once I know more.

Comment: you are probably missing the protobuf declaration - pattern I use - jdbc:phoenix:thin:url=http://<query_server>:<port>;serialization=PROTOBUF

Comment: @PaulBastide That seemed to do the trick! If you want to add it as a solution feel free to do so and I will accept it as the answer. If you don't feel like it, I will add it myself once I get my code tidied up ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @PaulBastide I managed to get a connection using the following link:

```
jdbc:phoenix:thin:url=http://<query_server>:<port>;serializa‌​tion=PROTOBUF
```

I also used the thin-client found together with the Phoenix distribution.